# What is the difference between POSIX reliable signals and POSIX real-time signals in Linux?

Tags: linux, signals, posix, real-time

I read the man page of a **signal** using 
[man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) where I see two types of signal. So, I have question,

What is the difference between **POSIX reliable signals** and **POSIX real-time signals** in Linux?

Answer (score 8):

These days, it might be better to phrase these as *ordinary* signal semantics versus *realtime* signal semantics.

In some early UNIX systems, signals were unreliable in that they could be "lost", because there was no facility to block signals (to keep them pending).  For example, code about to call *pause()* after checking a `wake_up_flag` set by a signal handler might miss the wake up instruction if the signal arrived just after the check but before the *pause()*.  Signal blocking and [*sigpause()*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigpause.3.html) are reliable improvements to this situation.

Additionally, the semantics of *signal()* meant that a user-defined signal handler was reset to SIG_DFL upon entry into the handler.  The usual technique, then, was to immediately re-install the user-defined disposition inside the signal hander.  However, since signals could not be blocked, that meant that there was a race condition in which a program could be signaled again and suffer the consequences of SIG_DFL.  In modern systems, [*sigaction()*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) addresses this situation reliably.

So, "reliable" signals are what most of us these days think of as ordinary signal semantics.  (For more information here, I'd recommend *Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment* by Stephens and Rago, specifically § 10.4 "Unreliable Signals")

[POSIX realtime signals](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04_02) add a few features over ordinary signals, for example, a new range of signals for application purposes (SIGRTMIN ... SIGRTMAX), the ability to queue pending signals, and the ability to deliver a word of data with a signal.