# Do masked signals get lost or put in a queue?

Tags: linux, signals, posix

If I set a signal handler (for `SIGCHLD`) with `sigaction` without `SA_NODEFER` and the process receives the same signal again while inside the handler, will the second signal be lost or will it be delivered when the handler returns?

Answer (score 3):

Historically, signals could get lost.  Initially, this was just a missing programming interface because `sigaction` and `sigprocmask` did not exist, so in order to temporarily stop delivery of a signal, you had to use the `signal` function with `SIG_IGN`, and of course during the time `SIG_IGN` was active, any signal would be gone if it arrived during that time.

With `sigprocmask` (and the clarified semantics of signal handlers installed with `sigaction`), signals can become pending, where the kernel records the fact that a signal is available, without actually delivering it.  Only once the signal is unblocked (or explicitly unblocked), it is consumed.

However, pending signals are not just simple counters (for each signal), but carry additional information, such as the sending PID and the signal value if the signal was generated using [`sigqueue`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigqueue.3.html).  This means the kernel actually has to allocate memory if it was to queue an arbitrary number of signals.  Linux does this for real-time signals only.  There is a per-user limit, `RLIMIT_SIGPENDING`, for the number of signals that can be queued:

```
$ ulimit -a | grep sign
pending signals                 (-i) 47913
```

See [`signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for details.

Non-real-time signals are not queued in this manner.  A process will observe only the first signal that becomes pending.  In a sense, subsequent signals may appear as lost, but at least one signal *is* delivered, so this is different from the original `SIG_IGN` race condition.

For certain non-real-time signals such as `SIGCHLD` and `SIGIO`, it may appear as if they are queued, but this is because they are generated once for specific events (tied to some existing kernel resources, such as a process), and multiple such events can happen while a signal is blocked.

Also see [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39533318/8316315).